# Apache camel split enrich

Tags: apache, apache-camel

Please help with subject.
Apache Camel 2.11.2.
I get answer from backend, transform to Map, split by MyObject and try to get additional info from other service by id of MyProject but ...
My route is:

```
<route id="test1">
 <from uri="restlet://lalalala"/>
 <to uri="get_answer_from_oracle"/>
 <setHeader headerName="convertClass">
   <simple>com.lalala.Result</simple>
 </setHeader>
 <process ref="convertProc"/>

<split strategyRef="testAgg">
 <simple>${body.resultList}</simple>
 <log message="Got777 ${body.testID}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
 <enrich uri="http://localhost:8880/servlet/lalalal" strategyRef="testAgg" />
</route>
```

I've get exception
org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: Result{id=5, property1=100, property2=750 ...}

I trying lots of variant but unsuccessfully.
Thank's

Comment: From my perspective you appear to be expecting an inputstream with one of your components, but you have a Result java object in the body.  You are going to need to provide more info if you would like a better answer though

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information like what does your particular route do and where are you getting this exception.. The exception clearly is a data mismatch.. Probably at the place where you are attempting de-serialization